# 3hr Time delay between a button press

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I would like to create a daily event, that is activated with a button press. So i would like to create a 3hr timers that disables the button once it has been pressed for 3hrs.

Im assuming i would use a `NSDate` code, but I'm unsure how the coding would go..

thanks.

Comment: fair call, will do better in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish such a task:

1. 1st button press - run event, capture current linux time. Example : 1332823536
2. add 10800 (which is 3 hours) which would make our example: 1332834336
3. save this number as an integer to NSUserDefaults
4. when the app starts back up check current time, turn it into an integer and make sure the current time is equal to or greater than the time you last saved (when the button was pushed)
5. if its NOT greater, disable the button - if it IS greater, enable the button.